# Using Ant, how can I create a file at a path that may not exist?

Tags: maven, ant, maven-antrun-plugin

Assume I have a directory structure like this:

```
src
  |- main
        |- webapp
                |- filters
                |- resources
                |- webapp
```

And an Ant touch task like this:

```
<touch file="src/main/webapp/filters/${more.path.to.file}"/>
```

Where `${more.path.to.file}` can vary greatly by configuration.

If all directories referenced in `more.path.to.file` do not already exist, the touch task fails, saying `No such file or directory`. Is there a way to create the file *and* create all directories, as needed?

Incidentally, I'm doing this within Maven's antrun plugin, in case that's relevant.

Thank you.

Comment: https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/mkdir.html. Also, touch has an mkdirs attribute: https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/touch.html.

Comment: As I said, touch has a mkdirs attribute.

Comment: Thanks. Deleted my previous comment because it didn't apply following your edit of your original comment. Can you place your comment in an answer? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The touch task has an mkdirs attribute: https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/touch.html.

Comment: Thank you. And can you either upvote my question or remove the downvote? I see no logical reason to have been downvoted.

Comment: Sometimes, even after careful viewing of documentation, a simple option can be overlooked. It's a human mistake, and it's too bad I've been penalized for it.